# Create a Dynamic List using Entity Framework in MVC Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I would like to make a list populate with vehicle makes using a stored procedure and Entity Framework but when it I get the following error:

*The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[VehicleInfo.Models.tblVehicle]'.*

**Model**

```
public partial class tblVehicle 
    {   
        public string BrandName{ get; set; }
    }
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index() 
    {
       VehicleDBContext db = new VehicleDBContext();

       var brandnames = db.prcGetMakes().ToList();

       return View(brandnames);
    }
```

**View**

```
@model IEnumerable<VehicleInfo.Models.tblVehicle>

<ul id="Makes">
   @foreach (var item in Model)
   {
      <li>@item.BrandName.Distinct()</li>
   }
</ul>
```

**Stored Procedure**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[prcGetMakes] 

AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT DISTINCT
        UPPER(BrandName) BrandName
    FROM
        tblVehicle
    ORDER BY
        BrandName
END
```

There must be something amazingly obvious that I am missing but I can't seem to work it out.

Please Help!

Comment: What is the type of the result of `db.prcGetMakes().ToList()`  ? Is it a list of string ? then the error is self explanatory. Your view is strongly typed to a list of `tblVehicle`. With the current view code, you basically need to return a list of `tblVehicle` objects.

Comment: Thank-you so much :)

Answer (score 3):

From the error message, It looks like the expression `db.prcGetMakes().ToList()`  in your action method returns a list of strings and you are passing that to the view. But your view is strongly typed to a list of `tblVehicle` objects, Hence getting the error message about the type mismatch.

Solution is to make both types match. You may update your view to be strongly typed list of `string` type

```
@model IEnumerable<string>

<ul id="Makes">
   @foreach (var item in Model)
   {
      <li>@item</li>
   }
</ul>
```